# How to iterate a table rows with JQuery and access some cell values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="checkout itemsOverview">
    <tr class="item">
        <td>GR-10 Senderos</td>
        <td><span class="value">15.00</span> €</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="1" maxlength="2" class="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>GR-10 Senderos<br/>GR-66 Camino de la Hermandad<br/>GR 88 Senderos del   Jarama<br/>Camino del Cid</td>
        <td><span class="value">45.00</span> €</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="quantity"   value="1" maxlength="2"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was trying with the next code to get the value and quantity of each item.

```
$("tr.item").each(function(i, tr) {
    var value = $(tr + " span.value").html();
    var quantity = $(tr + " input.quantity").val();
});
```

It is not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what specifically is not working for you?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
$("tr.item").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  var value = $this.find("span.value").html();
  var quantity = $this.find("input.quantity").val();
});
```

Comment: In order to not iterate all tables in page, better to replace $("tr.item").each(...) with $('#myTableId > tbody  > tr.item').each(...)

Comment: What does `$this = $(this)` do?

Comment: @qed stores the current contextual value of "this" into a variable called $this. If you were to nest another iterative call after the quantity assignment, calling "$(this)" would no longer be the same result. I believe Brian is just using standard best practice to avoid this confusion, but he could have just as easily named it "curRow", etc.

Answer (score 21):

do this:

```
$("tr.item").each(function(i, tr) {
    var value = $("span.value", tr).text();
    var quantity = $("input.quantity", tr).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var value = iterate('tr.item span.value');
var quantity = iterate('tr.item span.quantity');

function iterate(selector)
{
  var result = '';
  if ($(selector))
  {
    $(selector).each(function ()
    {
      if (result == '')
      {
        result = $(this).html();
      }
      else
      {
        result = result + "," + $(this).html();
      }
    });
  }
}
```