# How to retrieve hidden TD value from an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am wondering how could I retrieve a value from a td. I am working with displaying data from the database in the html table. I want to display all columns except for the "id" field which is set to be hidden.

I am using this jquery code:

```
function update(){
var $id = $(this).closest("tr").find("#pid").text();  
    alert($id);
}
```

Here's my ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'view.php',
            data:"",
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $("#body-data").append("<td hidden='hidden' id='pid'>"+data[i]['id']+"</td>"+
                                       "<td>"+data[i]['name']+"</td>"+
                                       "<td>"+data[i]['age'] +"</td>"+
                                       "<td>"+data[i]['gender'] +"</td>"+
                                       "<td>"+data[i]['email'] +"</td>"+
                                       "<td>"+data[i]['address'] +"</td>"+
                                       "<td><button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='update();'>Update</button></td>");
            }
            },

        });
```

I've tried anything to retrieve the id from an appended data in the html table but it just display nothing but blank.

Answer (score 0):

VanillaJS: document.getElementById('pid').innerText

Comment: Tried it. It partially works but the problem is it only retrieves the first row value when I tried to click on the second row the value still remains what the first row value has

Comment: Then create a class instead of a id, id should be unique always, then you will be able to go all over the class array getting the values

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out on how to retrieve the hidden td value.

I apply the answer found on the link: [Extract table row data with button on that row with jQuery each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787481/extract-table-row-data-with-button-on-that-row-with-jquery-each)