# How to get html <td> values using javascript in grid table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using mvc, I want to get the value of each and every `td` to edit in my `table`

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td id="val"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="" class="edit"/>
```

And in the javascript am using

```
var td = $(document).getElementById("val").innetHTML;

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
    if(td == null)
    {

    }
    else
        code......
})
```

But whenever am clicking the row edit button it is returning only the first row value, not getting the value of second and further.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have a typo in `innetHTML`, and you should write instead `document.getElementById()`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.edit').click(function()
    {
          $('table td').each(function() {
            var val = $(this).html();
            alert(val);
         });              
    });                  
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Same output even if am using your code.

Comment: i have multiple pages, each page is having 10 rows. whenever am clicking on edit button, it is returning first row value of that page, the same is happening for remaining pages. Am using datatables for my grid

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'class' attribute instead 'id':

```
<table>
<tr><td class="editVal"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="editVal"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="editVal"></td></tr>
</table>
```

You have to use JQuery for iterate each element:

```
$('.editVal').each(function(i) {
  // get value
  var $td = $(this).html;
  // set value
  $(this).html = 'Nuovo valore';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the values of a table one by one, I think [jquery each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is the function for you.

There is also another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891357/how-to-iterate-a-table-rows-with-jquery-and-access-some-cell-values) in SO with a good example.